How to check if button clicked has been disabled
I want to click the next button multiple times until it becomes disabled. As shown I am evaluating the page to get the button based on the class. However, this always returns null.
How can I achieve this?
let isDisabled = await page.$('.view-component [aria-label="Next Move"] .button-disabled') !== null;



while (!isDisabled) {
    nextBtn?.click();
    await new Promise(r => setTimeout(r, 2500));
    const component = await page.eval('.view-component [aria-label="Next Move"] .button-disabled');
    isDisabled = component !== null;
    console.log('Game End', isDisabled, JSON.stringify(component));
}


Can you provide the page you're automating, or a minimal example of it? This code isn't runnable and has multiple questionable practices: await page.eval('.view-component [aria-label="Next Move"] .button-disabled') isn't a valid function in Puppeteer, and nextBtn?.click() is missing await. Avoid sleeps. Are you trying to check the existence of an element with the class .disabled, or are you trying to check whether that element has a disabled attribute?

I am trying to check .disabled class when I click repeatedly. You click until the button is disable and then I exit the while loop.

All right, maybe try How can I check if selector exists in Puppeteer?.
